StringComparison and Contains Usage in C #
I'm making an .Net Maui app where it takes photo of a plant/flower and then send it to PlantNet API and it returns a 'scientific name', I then compare this 'scientific name' into my database of plant/flowers with scientificName.
But here's my problem - considering this code snippet, I need
string s = "Centaurea solstitialis L.";   // this is from PlantNet API
string z = "Centaurea solstitialis, C. melitensis";   // this is from my database

// this returns 'false' but I need this to return true since they're the same scientific name
Console.WriteLine("z.Contains(s): " + z.Contains(s, StringComparison.Ordinal));

I did tried to use the
s.Contains(z, StringComparison.Ordinal)
and s.Contains(z) and z.Contains(s)
but all returns false.

It returns false because z does not contain s. The L. part is not in Z

I'm not that familiar to scientific names of plants, but how do L. and C. melitensis  relate to one another? What is the logic for these to be equal? Should only the first two "words" in your strings be compared for instance?

The first two words are scientific name divided into: genus name (Centaurea), the species epithet (solstitialis).
The letter is the citation refers to author citation (lastname) (ex. Carl Linnaeus). I just need to compare the genus name and the species epithet

One solution is split the string on space and comma, and then compare the fisrt two itens of both arrays. That is considering that every string is in the formats you showed above.

@Magnetron that's what I thought, I was just thinking if there's another way to compare using 'Contains' since the two words are the same.

No, you cannot expect Contains to know what you mean, you have to implement yourself.

As far as i can see, the api responses also have a "scientificNameWithoutAuthor". Why not use that?

@Fildor I coded my model to only grabbed 'bestMatch' or the ScientificName, it's just when came up with a test data with authorship I stumbled on this one. But that's a good point let me see how easy to refactor my code to get also scientificNameWithoutAuthor.

You can use CommonPrefixLength to get the longest common start value, and compare that to what you want.
var length = s.AsSpan().CommonPrefixLength(z);
Console.WriteLine("Common Prefix: " + s.Substring(0, length));

